# Represent the reflection $k(x)$ on a line as $Ax+b$.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

The transformation $k$ is the reflection in the line $y = -x + 5$.
By using the translation $h$ that maps the point $(0, 5)$ to the origin, and
its inverse $h^{-1}$, determine $k$ in the form $Ax+b$.

Attempt:
The idea is to translate $(0,5)$ back to origin, reflect it on $y = -x$ and then move everything back.

$$ x' = x + h = x + (0,-5)^T$$

At origin, reflect about $y=-x$ 
$$ x'' = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot x + (5,0)^{T} $$
Now, finally to undo the first step, add the translation $h^{-1} = (0,5)^T$.
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot x + (5,0)^{T} + (0,5)^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot x + (5,5)^{T} $$
which is the required form of the transformation. 
I checked with an arbitrary point to confirm the result, but since I am beginner, I would like to know if my approach and solution are correct. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, you are committing a cardinal sin of mathematics here: Yoo are using the same variable to mean different things in this calculation. Sometimes $x$ is the $x$ coordinate in the plane. Other times it is a vector in the plane. NEVER do this. There are 26 letters in the alphabet, and if that isn't enough, you can use upper and lower case to represent different variables. And then you can use other alphabets or other fonts. There is no reason at all to use the same variable for two different things in a single calculation. All you accomplish by doing so is to confuse your self and others.

Comment: Otherwise, your solution is fine. To be absolutely sure, you can test 3 non-colinear points. Any affine transformation in the plane is uniquely determined by its actions on 3 non-colinear points.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.